# Trouble figuring out how to return this recursive function?

Tags: java, eclipse

New to the java programming language and confused how to run this code! I am using Eclipse.

```
public static String random(String n)
{
    int F = n.length();
    if(F <= 1) return n;
    String b = n.substring(0, F/2);
    String c = n.substring(F/2, F);
    return random(c) + random(b);
}
```

I am new to running java programs in the terminal window and I can't seem to figure out how to get the return value.

Answer (score 2):

Put it into a class like this

```
public class MyRandom {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(random("abc"));
   } 

   public static String random(String n) {
    int length = n.length();

    if (length <= 1)
        return n;
    String b = n.substring(0, length / 2);
    String c = n.substring(length / 2, length);
    return random(c) + random(b);
   }
}
```

and then right click on the file and choose "Run As"

Comment: Save the above code in MyRandom.java file, by terminal if you want first compile it with **javac MyRandom.java**, you will see a MyRandom.class then do **java MyRandom**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in your `main` method:

```
System.out.println(random("Hello"));
```

Since `random` method returns a `String`, you can print it out in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the call to your function in a stdout print like so:
`System.out.println(random("test"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
String returnValue = random("YourNString");
```

So the return value will be stored in `returnValue`

Then your can do `System.out.println(returnValue)`

Or simply do `System.out.println(random("YourNString"));`